# How to check if 2d vector element is in a certain index range

Tags: c++, vector

I want to check whether or not a certain element of a 2d vector is within an index range. For example, I have the following vector:

```
{1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
 6,  7,  8,  9,  10,
 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
```

How might I check whether or not the element number 7 (or `[1][1]`) is within the index range of 0 to 2 on the `x` axis and 0 to 1 on the `y` axis? Or in other words a `3x2` partition of the vector from the top left corner.

Answer (score 2):

For the y axis you can do it like this:

```
index/width < yLimit
```

For the x axis, it would be like this:

```
index%width < xLimit
```

where `width` is the width of the 2d array, and `xLimit` and `yLimit` are the maximum you want your x-axis number and your y-axis number to be respectively.

Note that this number should be greater than or equal to 0 anyway, since negative indices are not a thing in C++.

Also note that I use `<` here, but I recon if you want to include `1` or `2` in your possible indices, you should use `<=` instead.

If you want them together, a logical `and` will do nicely:

```
index/width < yLimit && index%width < xLimit
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any example values for all the variables? yLimit/xLimit for an example? I am having trouble implementing it.